# How to fix 400 Bad Request by php coding

Tags: php, 400, bad-request

Last weekend our server/app got bugged and some of your visitor are now getting Error 400 Bad Request everytime they visit our website.

I know this error was caused by malformed cookies and everything goes OK when the visitor manually clears browser cache, BUT...

Is there anyway I can force it to be cleared using PHP?

I had tried setting `header('Clear-Site-Data: "cache", "cookies", "storage", "executionContexts"');` as  first line in all files, but it didn't worked as the error is fired first =(

Comment: You could put a reverse proxy in front of the web server, eg. HAProxy, Varnish, and let them sanitize the cookies before they hit your web server.

Comment: It all depends on your application layout.

Comment: Sorry for missing information; I'm on Amazon EC2 LAMP